# javascript Object.keys and Object.values both return a sequence number instead of the actual key or value

Tags: javascript

Anyone have had an issue before where running javacript Object.keys or Object.values returns a sequence number as string instead of the actual key or value? In otherwords, if I have three properties in my object and I run e.g:

```
for(var value in Object.values(myObject)){
 console.log(value);
}
```

It prints out:

```
0
1
2
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? It is a JSON object, so the value is not just string, but nested, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Please include your ```myObject``` in the question.

Comment: A `for ... in` loop loops through the **keys** of an object, and `Object.values()` returns an array.

Comment: `Object.values(myObject)` returns an array, and `value` is the index in a `for .. in`. use `for ... of` to get the value instead.

Comment: Please add Array Object / object data

Comment: You should go for `for ... of` loop to log out the actual values of your object.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do this instead:

```
for (const value of Object.values(myObject)) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

`in` is for iterating through the property keys of an object, `of` for the values of an enumerable (like arrays). `var value in Object.values()` is numbers because those are the keys of the `Object.values(...)` *array*.